# Are there any good alternatives for Visio/PowerPoint?

Tags: powerpoint, visio

Are there any good alternatives for Visio/PowerPoint for drawing architectural diagrams. Both Visio and PowerPoint are annoying to use even for some of the simplest tasks. wondering if someone out there has a better suggestion.

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the alternatives I tried sucked! I just used PowerPoint, better than Visio!

Answer (score 19):

Try [diagrams.net](https://app.diagrams.net) (previously draw.io). It free and [open source](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio), it works natively in any browser and you can save locally or to Google Drive, OneDrive, Github and Gitlab. There's also a [Desktop app for Window, macOS and Linux](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/releases).

I am a developer of diagrams.net.

Answer (score 4):

I use Draw in OpenOffice for Visio alternatives... Seems to work okay.

Answer (score 4):

I recently discovered Google Docs Draw. Good for me.

Answer (score 3):

[gliffy.com](http://www.gliffy.com/)  for example.

Answer (score 3):

I use OmniGraffle for mac, and I enjoy using it. There is also smartdraw for PC. They are both good options for non-professional architectural diagrams. For more professional diagrams, CAD programs tend to have more options.

Answer (score 3):

ARIS Express --> can import Visio 2007 diagrams

Answer (score 3):

LucidChart all the way!

http://www.lucidchart.com

Just try it once.  Having used Visio extensively over the years--I can't tell you how satisfying LucidChart is to use.